# How can I create a function to reindex top X worst postgres indexes

Tags: postgresql, reindex

I'm trying to take the output of the following query and pass the indexes to another query that will perform a reindex. The end goal is to schedule a nightly job that will reindex the top 5 or 10 "most fragmented" indexes. Our application is highly transactional and can be rather large so we can't afford to do a nightly reindex of all tables. Also, we're running postgres 11 (so CONCURRENTLY) isn't an option.

...

```
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass
       --,s.leaf_fragmentation
FROM pg_index AS i
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON i.indexrelid = t.oid
   JOIN pg_opclass AS opc ON i.indclass[0] = opc.oid
   JOIN pg_am ON opc.opcmethod = pg_am.oid
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstatindex(i.indexrelid) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'i'
  AND pg_am.amname = 'btree'
AND s.leaf_fragmentation > 30
AND s.leaf_fragmentation != 'NaN'
AND left(relname,3) !='pg_'
ORDER BY leaf_fragmentation desc
LIMIT 10
```

...

Comment: It would be a very uncommon workload that would make that necessary (without bloating the table too). I think that you shouldn't do that.

Comment: why would you do that? what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe related example: we had one case where a table which holds 10 to 20 Million rows, about 100k to 5 Million inserted rows per day and a nightly delete of the oldest 100k to 5 Million rows. Auto Vacuum went over the table immediately after the nightly delete, but the indexes had several times more deleted pages than leaf pages. The query planner became confused when planning a complex SELECT and started reading an insane number of buffers during planning, causing massive CPU usage. Bernd Helmle told us to reindex and that solved the issue. That IS a very uncommon workload thow.

Comment: @drfumanchu Right. Partitioning might be a better solution.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I will do that. I should have listened better to you when you were teaching me ;-)